# php preg_macthing for tumblr avatar grabbing

Tags: php, tumblr

amm please kindly check this code? cos it won't work..

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("http://natadec0c0.tumblr.com/");
$avatar = preg_match('/<a rel="shortcut icon" href="(http+)"/', $page, $matches) ? $matches[1]: 'http://27.media.tumblr.com/avatar_749f6bc22627_128.png';

echo $avatar;
?>
```

To Grab copy this tag view-source:http://natadec0c0.tumblr.com/

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_fa85d9b5e571_16.png" />
```

whew almost half of hour im stuck in this problem.. hope someone can help me...

Comment: While workable for this and specific extraction tasks, keep in mind that your regex is not resilient against extraneous whitespace, or html serialization variations like changed parameter order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for an `<a rel...`, instead of a `<link rel...`.

Also, you'll likely want something like `(http.+?)` instead of `(http+)`.

A better better way for finding that link though would be something like:

```
if (preg_match('/<link.+?>/si', $page, $link_matches)
    && strpos($link_matches[0], 'shortcut icon') !== false
    && preg_match('/href\s*=\s*"(http:.+?)"/si', $link_matches[0], $matches))
{
    $avatar = $matches[1];
}
else
{
    $avatar = 'http://27.media.tumblr.com/avatar_749f6bc22627_128.png';
}
```

In the above example, you'd first be looking for `<link/>` tags, then look for the `href` attribute in the found link tags. Just in case they look a little differently from what you expect them to look like.

Comment: owhh <link rel.... my bad :) hehe, ahh so http.+? owhhh savior, thank so much @Radu....